# Attribute group not present when assigning it to the default attribute group

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Following [this](http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/) tutorial, I assumed that I can simply assign my attribute group to the default attribute group like so:

```c
static DEVICE_ATTR_RO(status);
static struct attribute *my_dev_attrs[] = {
    &dev_attr_status.attr,
    NULL
};
ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS(my_dev);

static int probe(struct spi_device *spi) {
    ...
    spi->dev.groups = my_dev_groups;
    ...
}
```

But no file appears at `/sys/bus/spi/drivers/my_dev/spi2.0`.
However, when I define the attribute like so:

```c
int ret
ret = sysfs_create_group(&spi->dev.kobj, &my_dev_group);
if (ret < 0)
    return ret;
```

I can see and correctly access the file at `/sys/bus/spi/drivers/my_dev/spi2.0`. Is there any further setup required for the first option?

Comment: Thanks, that't the trick! If you want, you can put that as an answer so I can set that as accepted answer.

Comment: Moved to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.groups` field of the `struct device` is not supposed to be used or assigned directly. The idea behind is to provide the static attribute groups and assign them via `.dev_groups` member of the respective `struct driver`. See, for example, [this code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/misc/pvpanic/pvpanic-pci.c#L106).

With that done, the driver core will take care of creating and removing them in a non-racy manner (that's why that field was appeared to begin with).